# How to call application.properties value in logback.xml file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to call local location value(c:/temp) from application.properties file in logback.xml file.

currently i am specify location value in logback.xml itself, it's working fine.

logback.xml

```
<configuration>

    <property name="LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %p %m%n" />
    <property name="APP_LOG_ROOT" value="c:/temp"/>
...
</configuration>
```

But i want to call value from application.properties file.

application.properties

'''
log.location.value = c:/temp
'''

what i have to change in logback.xml file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the below snippet in your **logback.xml** :

```
<property resource="application.properties" />
```

This will let you refer properties in a standard way

Example : ${app.name}.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured my logback-spring.xml as per Spring Boot Documentation, this might be a better solution.
Instead of calling the whole application.properties in your logback.xml file, you can refer to a specific property in the application.properties file like this:

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="APP_TIMEZONE" source="application.timezone" />
```

Then you can use the springProperty like this: **${APP_TIMEZONE}**.
This way you can call a specific value in the application.properties file.

```
<Pattern>
    %d{ISO8601,${APP_TIMEZONE}} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
</Pattern>
```